# Make a pie chart using chart.js in Django error

Tags: django, chart.js

I am building a budget tracker application and in dashboard page, I'd like to list different graphs. The pie chart is for expense structure showing how much expense is spent in certain categories. I'm facing two problems mainly. First one is the data of model in view doesn't pass through the template which results graph not showing. Second one is that I'm trying to show proportion of certain categories of expense, not a proportion of every expense(sum of accumulation of expense has to be calculated if they're in same category.) If I can get help, I'd be so much appreciated.

models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
TRANSACTION_CHOICES = [
    ('Expense','Expense'),
    ('Income','Income'),
]
transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, choices=TRANSACTION_CHOICES, default="Expense",null=True)
title = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length=30)
description = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length=200)
amount = models.DecimalField(blank=False, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
date_paid = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
time_paid = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)

CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
('Groceries', 'Groceries'),
('Salary', 'Salary'),
('Bills', 'Bills'),
('Rent', 'Rent'),
('Gym', 'Gym'),
('Restaurant', 'Restaurant'),
('Vacation', 'Vacation'),
('Travel', 'Travel'),
('Gift', 'Gift'),
('Investments', 'Investments'),
('Savings', 'Savings'),
('Entertainment', 'Entertainment'),
('Internet', 'Internet'),
('Healthcare', 'Healthcare'),
('Lifestyle', 'Lifestyle'),
('Insurance', 'Insurance'),
('Other', 'Other'),
]
category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
receipt = models.ImageField(upload_to='receipt_images', blank = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def receipt_url(self):
    if self.receipt and hasattr(self.receipt, 'url'):
        return self.receipt.url
```

views.py

```
def expense_structure(request):
#qs = Transaction.objects.values('category').annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount')).order_by('category')

# Retrieve user's transactions
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('date_paid')
# Extract data for graph
labels = []
data = []
expense = 0
for transaction in transactions:
    labels.append(transaction.date_paid.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
    if transaction.transaction_type == "Expense":
        expense = transaction.amount
    else:
        expense != transaction.amount
    data.append(expense)
# Create chart data
return JsonResponse(data={
    'labels': labels,
    'data': data,
})
```

expense_structure.html

```
{% extends 'base_content.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center my-3">
     <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <h4 class="card-title">Expense Structure</h4>
          </div>
          <canvas id="expense_structure" data-url="{% url 'expense_structure' %}"></canvas>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    var $expense_structure = $("#expense_structure");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $expense_structure.data("url"),
                        success: function (data) {
                            var ctx = $expense_structure[0].getContext("2d");
                            new Chart(ctx, {
                                type: 'bar',
                                data: {
                                labels: data.labels,
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: 'Expenses',
                                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                                    data: data.data
                                }]          
                                },
                                options: {
                                responsive: true,
                                legend: {
                                    position: 'top',
                                },
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'Expense Structure Bar Chart'
                                }
                                }
                            });

                            }
                        });

                        });

             </script>
 </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the entire queryset to the chart data, but you need to group the transactions by category and sum the amounts for each category to display the proportion of expenses under each category.

Update your `ExpenseStructureView` class with the code below:

```
class ExpenseStructureView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'expense_structure.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    qs = Transaction.objects.values('category').annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount')).order_by('category')
    context["categories"] = [d['category'] for d in qs]
    context["totals"] = [d['total_amount'] for d in qs]
    return context
```

The code has been updated to group the transactions by category and sum the amounts for each category, then pass the resulting data to the chart in the template.

After this you need to update your `expense_structure.html` template file with this:

```
{% extends 'base_content.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Expense Structure!</h1>
<script>
    // jquery function
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: {{ categories|safe }},
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Expense',
                    data: {{ totals|safe }},
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
});
    });
</script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" 
height="100"></canvas>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Any Questions are welcome here...

Comment: Thank you. I still have empty graph in html page. I can't diagnose still...

Comment: @Jae - Before rendering it into html/js can you make sure you are getting proper data from ORM? Just try it on your template as a test to view the data you are getting.

Comment: I have tried with your code but it did not work. So I modified code using ajax. It shows the graph but I don't know how to configure the expense into the graph now... Could you help?